# How to run more complex cfa models with lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to learn lavaan by messing around and building different models in Rstudio. I'm currently happy with simple cfa models and I'm now trying more complex models. The paper I am currently working on is Friedman et al. (2008) (doi:10.1037/0096-3445.137.2.201). I am essentially trying to replicate the model in the image below (without the top factors, that's why they are cut-off):

[image]

Specifically, I am trying to take the 9 observed variables (Anti - Cat) which are reflecting performance on cognitive lab-tasks and model them to 3 latent variables (common - shifting-specific). All 9 variables are believed to relate to "common", 3 specific variables relate to "updating-specific", and 3 other specific variables related to "shifting-specific". Below is what I have done so far and the error I am facing. I would love help resolving the below errors.

First, I created some fake-data to work with

```
id <- c(1:100)
#inhibition task outcomes
Antisaccade <- runif(100)
StopSignal <- runif(100)
Stroop <- runif(100)
#updating task outcomes
KeepTrack <- runif(100)
LetterTask <- runif(100)
TwoBack <- runif(100)
#shifting task outcomes
NumLtr <- runif(100)
ColourShape <- runif(100)
CatSwitch <- runif(100)
#make a dataframe
dat <- data.frame(id, Antisaccade, StopSignal, Stroop,
                  KeepTrack, LetterTask, TwoBack,
                  NumLtr, ColourShape, CatSwitch)
```

Next, I used `cfa()` in lavaan to build what I thought was an appropriate model

```
library(lavaan)
CFAtest <- 'common =~ Antisaccade + StopSignal + Stroop +
                  KeepTrack + LetterTask + TwoBack +
                  NumLtr + ColourShape + CatSwitch
        updating_specific =~ KeepTrack + LetterTask + TwoBack
        shifting_specific =~ NumLtr + ColourShape + CatSwitch'
CFAtest_res <- cfa(CFAtest, data = dat, estimator = "ML")
summary(CFAtest_res, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

However, this lead to errors around standard errors not being calculated (model potentially unidentified).
So I did some research and found another potential way with `sem()` from lavaan. This is presented below

```
nested <- '
        level: 1
        Common =~ Antisaccade + StopSignal + Stroop +
                  KeepTrack + LetterTask + TwoBack +
                  NumLtr + ColourShape + CatSwitch
        level: 2
        updating_specific =~ KeepTrack + LetterTask + TwoBack
        shifting_specific =~ NumLtr + ColourShape + CatSwitch'
nested_res <- sem(nested, data = data, cluster = ) #what would we put here...
summary(nested_res, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

But, with this one I get asked about the 'cluster' argument to which I do not know how to respond. Putting `cluster = "cluster"` returns an error as there is no cluster variable in the dataset (and I don't know how or why I need one...).

My questions are:

1. Are either of these approaches appropriate for replicating Friedman et al. (2008) model?
2. Why does the first example fail to proceed standard errors and can such a model be trusted?
3. What would I do about `cluster =`  in the 2nd example?
4. Which of these is best (or is there another option) and does anything need amending?

Thank you so much,
Jack

Comment: Your questions are not really specific to an issue with R or programming in general. You'd be more likely of getting an answer to these questions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The `cluster=` argument is used when rows of data are nested in groups, not for "clusters" of indicators.  Your first syntax is probably fine, but you should add a `orthogonal=TRUE` to your `cfa()` call, so that the factors are not correlated.  Also, you are simulating independent variables, so there is no covariance structure to model.  Try fixing parameters in your syntax in order to `simulateData()` with your specified covariance structure.